# Laravel create multiple parameter URL

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to pass multiple parameters to the URL class in Laravel 4. I've tried the following code:

```
<li>  
  <a href="{{ URL::to('questions/', $chapter->id, false); }}">
    <span>Chapter {{ $chapter->chapter_num }}: {{ $chapter->name }}</span>
  </a>  
</li>
```

This seems to work for one parameter. How do I pass multiple parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the parameters in an array. For example:

```
array($chapter->id, $parameter2, $parameter3, false)
```

This may also help: http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Routing.UrlGenerator.html#76-98

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can pass multiple parameters as an array.

This should work:
`URL::to('questions/', array($chapter->id,$other->propr), false)`

Hope it helps!